# How do I properly structure, configure, and bundle shared code in a Typescript AWS stack monorepo?

Tags: javascript, typescript, aws-lambda, monorepo, npm-workspaces

I'm having trouble getting my head around how to configure this setup so it bundles, builds, and executes without problems. The crux of the issue lies in how AWS Lambda cannot properly bundle/reference a shared library in a monorepo. This is likely due to hoisting and/or symlinking.

It's a fullstack serverless (AWS) monorepo using `npm workspaces`, built entirely in TS, with React as a front-end. I'm looking to create a great DX that debugs easily on a local machine and is deployed via the CDK. Using `Serverless Framework` *strictly* for local debugging.

Happy to share the final repo once it all works! I'd even like to do a writeup as I feel like this is valuable to a lot of devs.

I'm not *married* to npm workspaces, I just wanted things to be as bare-bones simple as possible, and using `npm` means not installing another package manager. This is why I avoided any monorepo frameworks like bit, rush, etc. Open to suggestions here, but would prefer the absolute least configuration possible to get this working. We're **buried** in configuration complexity these days.

Monorepo is structured like so:

```
my-monorepo/
├── node_modules
├── packages/
│   ├── lib/
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   ├── random.ts
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   └── tsconfig.json
│   ├── lambda/
│   │   ├── test.ts
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   └── tsconfig.json
│   └── web/
│       └── react-vite/
│           ├── App.tsx
│           ├── package.json
│           └── tsconfig.json
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.base.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

I'm simply trying to make it so all external and internal npm package references work, so I can share code between all projects out of the `/lib` folder. Therefore I'm testing with one local package function and one third-party, `ulid`.

Ideally, everything gets bundled automatically, across the stack, and there aren't a bunch of build steps and workarounds. Using `Vite` and CDK's `NodejsFunction` construct should allow that, and those are the only contact-points for the code in the `/lib` package.

Here's `lambda/test.ts`:

```js
import { ulid } from "ulid";
import { random } from "@my-monorepo/lib";

export async function routesHandler(event: any) {
    try {
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            // body: JSON.stringify(`${random.randomPhrase()} Lambda!`)
            body: JSON.stringify(`Hello Lambda! How about a ULID? -> ${ulid()}`)
        };
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("It's dead:", e);
    }
}
```

This executes just fine, and prints:

```
Compiling with Typescript...
Using local tsconfig.json - ./packages/lambda/tsconfig.json
Typescript compiled.
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": "\"Hello Lambda! How about a ULID? -> 01HE33FGF9DE4Q6H8K1KP42KEA\""
}
```

When I try to call from the `random` module by swapping the body lines in the lambda above, like this:

```
return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(`${random.randomPhrase()} Lambda!`)
    //body: JSON.stringify(`Hello Lambda! How about a ULID? -> ${ulid()}`)
};
```

I get this:

> import * as random from "./random";
> ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I tried to manually `tsc` the `/lib` project and change the main reference in `package.json` to `"main": "build/index.js"`, and get it working locally for the lambda, while debugging w/ serverless framework.

It also didn't help me at all once the Lambda was deployed to AWS. I still get this error on execution:

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module '@my-monorepo/lib'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module '@my-monorepo/lib'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/task/index.js",
    "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1087:17)",
    "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)",
    "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)",
    "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"
  ]
}
```

It also breaks the reference in Vite for some reason, for which I'd rather not try to wrangle, since I'd like to avoid manually transpiling to JS before deploying, anyhow...if possible.

Another thing I took a shot at, was just making a direct reference to the `/lib`, which **works across the board**, but isn't very "monorepo-y". It works locally and in AWS, so why wouldn't I? Would my bundles blow out in size as my /lib size and usage grows? I don't anticipate putting more than shared types and validation schemas in there, as well as some basic utility code.

```js
import { random } from "../lib";

export async function routesHandler(event: any) {
    try {
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(`${random.randomPhrase()} Lambda!`)
        };
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("It's dead:", e);
    }
}
```

But I digress...moving on w/ the assumption that `/lib` should be treated like a monorepo package...

Here's the CDK stack I'm deploying with:

```js
export class LambdaStack extends Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        const prototypeLambda = new NodejsFunction(this, "PrototypeLambda", {
            functionName: "prototypeLambda",
            handler: "routesHandler",
            runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_18_X,
            timeout: Duration.minutes(3),
            entry: "../lambda/test.ts",
            bundling: {
                nodeModules: [
                    "@my-monorepo/lib",
                    "ulid"
                ]
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Once deployed, you can see `ulid` is present in `node_modules`, but my lib is not:

[image]

Here's the test /lib:

**lib/index.ts:**

```
import * as random from "./random";
import * as model from "./model/model";

export {
    random,
    model
};
```

**lib/random.ts:**

```
const randomPhrase = (): string => {
    const phrases = [
        "Gadzooks!",
        "Eureka!",
        "D'oh!",
        "Egads!",
        "Bazinga!"
    ];
    return phrases[Math.round(Math.random() * phrases.length)];
};

export {
    randomPhrase
};
```

It has to be a combination of `tsconfig` props that I'm getting wrong, because I can execute code from the `/lib` within `App.tsx` in the `web/react-vite` project, it renders and works as expected. Here's that snippet:

```
import { random } from "@my-monorepo/lib";

function App() {
    return (
        <div>Welcome to React...{random.randomPhrase()}</div>
    )
}

export default App
```

I see what I should:

[image]

Here's the root config stuff:

**./package.json**

```
{
    "name": "my-monorepo",
    "private": true,
    "workspaces": [
        "packages/lambda",
        "packages/web/react-vite",
        "packages/lib"
    ],
    "devDependencies": {
        ...  
    },
    "dependencies": {
        ...
    }
}
```

**./tsconfig.base.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2022",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "declaration": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "composite": true
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
    "include": [
        "packages/lib/*",
        "packages/lib/**/*"
    ]
}
```

**./tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "packages/lambda"
        },
        {
            "path": "packages/lib"
        }
    ]
}
```

/lib config files:

**lib/package.json:**

```
{
    "name": "@my-monorepo/lib",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.ts"
}
```

**lib/tsconfig.json:**

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json"
}
```

/lambda config files:

**lambda/package.json**

```
{
    "name": "@my-monorepo/lambda",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "test.ts",
    "dependencies": {
        "@my-monorepo/lib": "^1.0.0",
        "ulid": "^2.3.0"
    }
}
```

**lambda/tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json"
}
```

I took a look at using Lambda Layers as well, but the configuration to get this working both locally, where it's debuggable in VS Code, as well as properly deploying, is fairly painful.

Comment: You set package.json to type module but then set tsconfig to use module commonjs. Those are incompatible settings. First figure out if you want your project to be ESM or CJS.

Comment: @morganney I know. I've tried all variations of each, exclusively. Tweaking that doesn't solve this. The crux of the issue is that lambda doesn't bundle or handle TS npm packages whereas the Vite app does. I can manually build the /lib and get the transpiled JS to work locally, but it doesn't work for deployment, and it's also not ideal and am looking for a better way.

Comment: You definitely don't want to use mixed module settings. I see no reason why the lambda package should behave differently from the web based on what I see here. If you have a link to your repo I can take a better look by checking it out and running the code. Otherwise, I'm working on a project with a very similar setup. Instead of a lib package there is a components package, but the idea is the same. Maybe it can help you: https://github.com/morganney/busmap

Comment: @morganney You're right - removed the `"type": "module"` stuff - same errors and issues though. Sorry for the confusion. Looks like you're using an Express API? I also added the CDK construct I'm deploying with, and details there.

Comment: Like I said before, with this issue it is better to debug with an actual reproducible example. You need to make sure you build your packages prior to deployment, and your lambda stack also needs to correctly reference the built dependency on lib. Get it working locally first **without hacking the main field in package.json**. BTW, the main field shouldn't reference a `.ts` file, it needs to correctly reference a published build path/file.

Comment: @morganney Yes, this is mentioned in "Update 1". It does work locally by building and referencing the .js file in the build folder, when using serverless to debug. It's the deployment part that I struggle with, at that point. Was angling for a bundling solution to avoid that build step, if possible. Appreciate the insights.

Comment: Please do not post "Update" sections to questions - just edit the whole question to be "updated" to help us understand the problem in one reading.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Damned if you do, damned if you don't - I've had others correct me to the contrary, and even edit my posts and add such things. Would "I also tried" be more descriptive? At some point, the information is relevant and helpful but would just make the post messy.

Comment: It’d be good to have the ‘this is working locally’ as the focal point of the question. The question needs to read correctly from top to bottom; anyone that says otherwise is wrong. And don’t worry; we can filter out messy info but good to have everything especially as you have a running bounty.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Fair enough - hope this last edit helps.

Comment: How exactly is the cdk deployment supposed to work while the lib package has its main field set to a `.ts` file?

Comment: @morganney That's a great question. It works perfectly when referenced directly e.g. `../lib` because Serverless bundles and builds it automatically, locally, and NodejsFunction in CDK does the same upon deployment. Same for Vite on run or build, only with Vite I can use the actual package reference via the monorepo e.g. `@my-monorepo/lib`. I'm trying to achieve this with the Lambda so it works locally and deploys properly. Again, looking to avoid the manual build step. Like I mentioned before when you asked - all details above.